# Making a Monome using ArduinoMega256

Tags: arduino

I'm attempting to make a Monome clone. ([What is a Monome?](http://monome.org/)) Now hardware wise I should be fine. I ordered 64 buttons (4 4x4 Button Pads) and making the PCB to hook it up to Arduino Mega. So I will be able to control the LED states and read the button states. I'm also able to read button numbers in the serial Monitor in the Arduino IDE. My question is how can I make my hardware emulate the actual Monome and use the software built for Monome? Is the serial protocol the only option using the Arduino? I know there is a project that already does this called Arduinome but I'd like to make mine from scratch. Monome Software has a really long tool chain which is giving me a headache.

Request: Can you point me in the right direction?

Question: Would it be hard to write a piece of software that that acts as a bridge between my hardware and Monome software?

**Edit (Clarification):**

My main problem is that I don't know how to approach the problem of connecting my hardware and the already made software. Basically I need to know what information I need to channel into which location using which protocol on my computer (if that makes any sense).

Comment: Specific questions about electronic design are required.

Comment: well it is specifically non-specific.

Comment: In that case it has to be marked as _overly broad_. Also, "Would it be hard ..." is a bit hard to answer when we do not know your skill level.

Comment: "My question is how can I make my hardware emulate the actual Monome and use the software built for Monome?" This would require thorough reverse-engineering of the Monome product. That's too involved a question to answer in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I'm really just asking for some key words which I can google or read up on. And yes, it is not a great question, but that is really part of my problem.

Comment: No, I'm not going to follow a link to get basic mandatory information.  Since knowing whatever this "monome" thing is is important to your question, you should at least provide a basic explanation.  As it stands now, this is not a real question.

Answer (score 2):

> I ordered 64 buttons (4 4x4 Button Pads) and making the PCB to hook
>   it up to Arduino Mega....
>   My question is how can I make my hardware emulate the actual Monome
>   and use the software built for Monome?

I've never noticed the [Monome](http://monome.org/) before, it seems very cool! However I think it will be a bit much for an AtMega to handle. I would recomend using 1 or more atmega's to detect the button presses and toggle the LED's. Then you should use a 32bit ARM processor for the audio and communication between the AtMega(s).

> Request: Can you point me in the right direction?

You may want to look into using a [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) as the main ARM processor. I believe they have analog audio out.

> Question: Would it be hard to write a piece of software that that acts
>   as a bridge between my hardware and Monome software?

It wouldn't be much work. However 'hard' is in the eye of the beholder! ;)

That looks like a really cool and fun project, best of luck!

---

It looks like using a Raspberry Pi has been discussed on monome.org: http://monome.org/community/discussion/13723/x

Comment: From looking through the docs, it looks like the Monome is actually already based on ATmega CPUs. It doesn't actually do any audio stuff locally. It's basically a big keyboard. They're also using a bunch of NXP SPI interfacing LED drivers to handle the LEDs too, so they don't have to do any PWM locally either.

Comment: @ConnorWolf Interesting, I haven't had the chance to look into it, Thanks.

Comment: Yes Connor Wolf is right. The Monome is used to control software on a computer and does not generate audio signal itself. Thanks for your answer though.